# Trying to call two functions on the same input field but only calls one

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two working functions which I want to assign to two inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="start0" value="0" name="start[]" onkeyup="displayTotal();"/>
<input type="text" id="end0" value="0" name="end[]"  onkeyup="displayTotal();"/>
```

I would like to be able to use a `displayHoras();` `onkeyup` for those two also. When I use `displayHoras();` instead of `displayTotal();` it works, but when I call both of them like this it doesn't:

```
<input type="text" id="start0" value="0" name="start[]" onkeyup="displayTotal();displayHoras();"/>
<input type="text" id="end0" value="0" name="end[]"  onkeyup="displayTotal();displayHoras();"/>
```

Any help will be welcomed.

I'll share the code of both functions because... who knows? The problem might be there, right?

```
function displayTotal()
{
   var tableRows = document.getElementById('budgetTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
   var totalDays = tableRows.length - 3; //Don't count the header rows and the Total rows

   var totalPrice = 0;

   var price = filterNum(document.getElementById( 'txtPrice' ).value);
   var totalField = document.getElementById( 'txtTotal' );

   var tempHours = 0;
   var tempTotal = 0; 

   for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
   {
       tempHours = document.getElementById("end" + i).value - document.getElementById("start" + i).value;
       tempTotal = tempHours * price;

       document.getElementById("total" + i).innerHTML = formatCurrency(tempTotal);
       totalPrice += tempTotal;
   }
   totalField.value = formatCurrency(totalPrice*1.21); 
}

function displayHoras()
{
    var tableRows = document.getElementById('budgetTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var totalDays = tableRows.length - 3;

    var tempHours = 0;
    var tempTotal = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
    {
       tempHours = document.getElementById("end" + i).value - document.getElementById("start" + i).value;
       document.getElementById("totalHoras" + i).innerHTML = tempHours;         
    }    
}
```

EDIT: I added the functions that create the table below.

```
function keyUpCall() {displayHoras(); displayTotal();}
function addRowToTable()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('budgetTable');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length - 4;
    var iteration = lastRow;
    var entry = iteration - 1; //because we started with day0, etc 
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

    // day cell
    var cellDay = row.insertCell(0);
    cellDay.appendChild(createInput('text','dia' + entry, '', keyUpCall, 'dia' + entry));

    // start cell
    var cellStart = row.insertCell(1);
    cellStart.appendChild(createInput('text','start' + entry, 0, keyUpCall, 'start' + entry));

    // end cell
    var cellEnd = row.insertCell(2);
    cellEnd.appendChild(createInput('text','end' + entry, 0, keyUpCall, 'end' + entry));

    // precio unitario
    var cellPrecioUnitario = row.insertCell(3);
    cellPrecioUnitario.appendChild(createInput('text', null, '$36', null, null));

    // total HOras
    var cellTotalHoras = row.insertCell(4);
    cellTotalHoras.id = 'totalHoras' + entry;

    // total cell
    var cellTotal = row.insertCell(5);
    cellTotal.id = 'total' + entry;

}

function createInput(type, id, value, action, name)
{   
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = type;
    el.id = id;
    el.value = value;
    el.onkeyup = action;
    el.name = name;
    return el;
}
```

At this point, the action is not even attached for some reason.

Edit2: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM!!! IUPI!! it was this line:

```
var totalDays = tableRows.length - 3;
```

In the previous version of this form I was using 3 extra rows, my client got me to add a couple extra ones for Tax and without Tax result. I changed it to:

```
var totalDays = tableRows.length - 5;
```

And that fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a single function that calls both functions

`function function1(){
displayTotal();
displayHoras();}`

Comment: I did that, the thing is, I'm creating these elements through js too. I have these two functions for this purpose, and it only seems to use displayTotal(). The function uses something like this:    function createInput(type, id, value, action, name). An I'm using function1() now as an action, but it only uses displayTotal()

Comment: In this case, did you check if displayTotal() doesn't have runtime errors. This would explain why the other method is not executed

Comment: Well it's working, so I'm not quite sure how could I check that. I'm not very used to js, maybe I should use an event listener, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet

Comment: I have a preference for firebug on firefox. It tells me when an error has occurred.

Comment: Well, I get a lot of these in firebug: document.getElementById("end" + i) is null. I don't know why though, because the elements created are indeed called "end1", "end2", etc

Comment: is the error "document.getElementById("end" + i) " or document.getElementById("end1") ? In the first case, it means that the method js syntax is incorrect otherwise it might the attribute of the called object

Comment: Amine, I just added the code that creates the table. It's supposed to be ("end" + i) I don't know why it's not working. Kind of dizzy right now ;D

Comment: The table creation seems correct but can you check at which iteration of the for loop you have the problem :for(var i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
   .....

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating a function that then calls your two functions, e.g.:

```
function handleKeyUp() { // Or `updateDisplay` or some such
    displayTotal();
    displayHoras();
}
```

Putting too much text within the `onXYZ` attributes is problematic (though I'm not immediately seeing why yours isn't working).

---

**Off-topic 1**: I'd also suggest hooking up event handlers using DOM2 methods ([`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) on standards-compliant browsers, [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on IE8 and below) rather than using DOM0 mechanisms like `onXYZ` attributes.

**Off-topic 2**: A JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) can help smooth over browser differences (and even bugs) like the event attachment stuff above, as well as providing lots of handy utility functionality. Totally optional, but using one helps you concentrate on what you're actually trying to do, without worrying about slightly different plumbing in various different browsers.

Comment: I understand what you mean about the jQuery and I'm definitely going to develop my skills on that on my next project, ...this one is already getting too long and I just want to finish it

Comment: @biggest_rage: Been there. :-) Good luck with it,

Answer (score 1):

old school javascript ^^

try this instead of the attribute variant, and use bugzilla, or a javascript debugger

```
var checks_keyup = function() {
    displayTotal();
    displayHoras();
}

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
    if(/^(start|end)/.test(inputs[i].id))
        inputs[i].onkeyup = checks_keyup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling second function withing the first function itself,

```
function displayTotal()
{
\\.....your code

 displayHoras();

}
```